# locate corresponding JS source of code which is not optimized by V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8, jit

I try to optimize the performance of a node.js application and therefore I am analyzing the behavior of V8's JIT compiler.

When running the application via `node --trace_deopt --trace_opt --code_comments --print_optcode ...`, the output contains many recurring lines like the following:

```
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x490a8b4aa69 <SharedFunctionInfo>]
```

**How can I find out which javascript code corresponds to `0x490a8b4aa69`?**

The full output is available [here](https://gist.github.com/d936067bd20cc0214a9c1245c70fcaad).

Comment: Always name your functions :-)

Comment: @Bergi any real-world advice? :)

Comment: What version of v8 (or Node.js) was this on? That error message used to be around line 10200 of `v8/src/objects.cc`, but is no more. *It basically means no optimization was currently employed for a particular trace. Possibly because it was unused, or used sufficiently infrequently. It may have likely been a Node.js library function. The address provided is in memory. You'd have to have attached a debugger to v8 and load the symbol for the SharedFunctionInfo at that location. Possibly breakpoint on the line that produces the message too.*

Comment: I may convert that to an answer if I can get more detail about the v8 version you're using.

Comment: @TylerY86 it was node version 4.5; do you know why this message is gone? in newer v8 versions, is there any other indication to find out whether a function has NOT been optimized?

Comment: Eh, I don't think it is that useful to know what was *not* optimized, as there are lots of things that don't get optimized... just take the output from trace_opt and assume everything else isn't. It was kind of just a hint that a check was performed for optimized code, and none was there are the time. Try `--trace_codegen` and work backwards? This looks to be a very time consuming thing to research.

Comment: I *do* know who can answer this question though. Thorsten Lorenz http://stackoverflow.com/users/97443/thorsten-lorenz

Comment: @TylerY86 could you please convert your comments into an answer?

Comment: Sure... but I haven't done any additional research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message used to be around line 10200 of `v8/src/objects.cc`, but is no more. It basically means no optimization was currently employed for a particular trace. Possibly because it was unused, or used sufficiently infrequently. It may have likely been a Node.js library function. The address provided is in memory. You'd have to have attached a debugger to v8 and load the symbol for the `SharedFunctionInfo` at that location. Possibly breakpoint on the line that produces the message too.

I don't think it is that useful to know what was not optimized, as there are lots of things that don't get optimized... just take the output from `--trace_opt` and assume everything else isn't. It was kind of just a hint that a check was performed for optimized code, and none was there are the time. Maybe try `--trace_codegen` and work backwards.

This looks to be a very time consuming thing to research.
[**Thorsten Lorenz**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97443/thorsten-lorenz) would be *the guy* to ask about this.